# No files seen on desktop folder of old Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, data-recovery

I attached drive of my old and not working laptop, to another laptop via USB (like an external drive) . Old Windows was password protected. i can access inside of my old Windows user, folder and even files, except Desktop folder. I can only see installed program icons and no any other files i had on desktop.

1 - Is this still about permission problem? no ACCESS DENIED error shown when clicking on folder.

2 - I tried changing permission of desktop folder to "Everyone". no luck. any other suggestion?

(Windows 7)

Comment: I'm not into Windows so treat it with a huge grain of salt. Check other folders like `Users\*\Desktop`, for two reasons: (1) I believe `C:\Users\All Users\Desktop` is shared between all users (it's uncommon to have files there, still I think it's technically possible). (2) When you cosmetically rename a user in Windows, the `C:\Users\something` location stays the same. After some heavy cosmetic renaming you can end up with locations not corresponding to usernames being displayed. It's possible the location you checked had been set up for another user before renaming.

Comment: I'm not on laptop now, but as i remember i browsed every user inside of USER folder including "All users" folder, etc. but their desktop folder was empty. anyway I'll check that again with more precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This is not a permission issue or you wouldn’t have been able to open the folder. Even then, if there was any permission issue with the individual files, you would still see them.

Unfortunately, the answer here is that the files don’t exist where you are looking.